# Объединить заголовки столбцов в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть условная таблица которую экспортирую из pandas в excel. Выглядит она примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли в pandas объединить только названия столбцов по типу. Чтобы при экспорте в excel она выглядела таким образом? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем случае мы можете применить метод multiindex к колонкам так же, как и к индексу:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=['a','b','c','z']) # генерируем df
                                                                    # для примера

          a         b         c         z
0  0.530421 -0.552079 -0.710845  0.709165
1  1.303415  1.537050 -1.491708 -0.290332
2 -0.705289 -0.026359 -1.791948 -0.162700
3  0.926152 -0.650124 -0.428592 -0.423194
```

и делаем мультииндекс для столбцов:

```
arrays = [['устройство', 'устройство', 'устройство', 'место'], df.columns]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays)

  устройство                         место
           a         b         c         z
0   0.530421 -0.552079 -0.710845  0.709165
1   1.303415  1.537050 -1.491708 -0.290332
2  -0.705289 -0.026359 -1.791948 -0.162700
3   0.926152 -0.650124 -0.428592 -0.423194
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваше решение работает!